# How to connect to specific local MongoDB instance in Spring Boot Dockerised application?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have developed simple **Spring Boot Application** that performs **CRUD** operations using **MongoDB** as database. I have deployed that application in **Docker** but I get null values while doing **GET Request** for any items stored in MongoDB. Some of the files required for Docker are provided below:

**Dockerfile:**

```
  VOLUME /tmp
  ADD build/libs/Spring-Boot-MongoDB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar SpringMongoApp.jar
  ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo:27018/otp","-jar","/SpringMongoApp.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"
services:
  api-database:
    image: mongo:3.2.4
    container_name: "springboot-mongo-app"
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: otp
    networks:
      - test-network

  api:
    image: springboot-api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - api-database
    networks:
      - test-network

networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=api-database
```

> When I checked the **MongoDb Docker container** using container ID, it is automatically getting connected to **test** database but not to **otp** database which I have mentioned in environment section of **docker-compose.yml** file.

Comment: Can you share please how do you "I checked the MongoDb Docker container using container ID"? If you run **mongo** without any parameter, it connects to test database (empty) by default wihich is normal.

Comment: docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash

Comment: run please **mongo otp**

Comment: U mean to check the values or what? Mention clearly about the steps

Comment: Once you access inside container, run `mongo otp`. It should connect desired database.

Comment: Yes it does connect but still  I am getting null values when I hit GET request in browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209500/discussion-between-valijon-and-ajay).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your docker container is not persistent, the database will be erased and re-created again each time you run your docker container.

If you add `VOLUME` to persist `/data/db`, you will get desired result.

> I assume your have directory  `data/db` in the same place where you have stored `docker-compose.yml`. You may setup custom directory (i.e `/tmp/data/db`)

Try this one:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"
services:
  api-database:
    image: mongo:3.2.4
    container_name: "springboot-mongo-app"
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - "./data/db:/data/db"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: otp
    networks:
      - test-network

  api:
    image: springboot-api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - api-database
    networks:
      - test-network

networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**Note:** First time, it will be *empty* database. If you create collections, insert records, etc... it will be saved in `./data/db`

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE` you should use `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE`

Comment: What if you change -Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo:27018/otp to -Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://api-databse:27018/otp in the Docker file

Comment: If it didn't work, remove the line in application.properties